# Do jQuery stuff on xhr responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there way to do jQuery stuff to responseText BEFORE I put it into the page. I want something like this, I make simple jQuery $.get or whatever and my callback looks like:

```
var callback = function(xhr,status) {
   var text = xhr.responseText;
   // I want so,mething like  $(text).$("#nameOfSomething").val("new value");
   $("#nameOfDivInPage").html(text);
}
```

And the div inside the text will have the html with the new value set in the #nameOfSomething  field.

I want to do jQuery-y things to text before I put it into the page.

Any Way to do this?

Comment: The response is just text, not html node. Maybe change them to html nodes with [jQuery.parseHTML()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/). Be careful though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make any text a jQuery object just like that.

```
var callback = function(xhr,status) {
   var text = xhr.responseText;
   // I want so,mething like  $(text).$("#nameOfSomething").val("new value");

   var newContent = $(text)
   newContent.filter("#nameOfSomething").val("new value");

   $("#nameOfDivInPage").html(newContent);
}
```